# how to replace some character's of String

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a numeric String i want to change the String first three character's by another character

Suppose I have a String like  `0333XXXXXXX` and `+38333XXXXXXX`. if the first character of String is `+38` i want to replace it with "0" while remaining String remain the same Here is my code

```
        private String modifyNumber(String num) {
                if (num.startsWith("+38")) {
                    num.replaceFirst("+38", "0");}
                   return num;}
```

"+38" is not accepting in `num.replaceFirst`.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37043761/3981656

Comment: ofcourse +92 is not accepted since it needs regular expression see my modified answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37043690/5870896

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use string replace method. see below

```
String number = +9231235410;
String newNumber = number.replace("+92","0");
```

**EDIT:**

this one is base on your code

```
 private String modifyNumber(String num) {
            if (num.startsWith("+92")) {
                num = num.replaceFirst("\\+(92)", "0");}
            return num;}
```

**Note:**

- In java, you need to have double backslash since the `\` is a unique
  java character.
- Java strings are immutable method. you need to assign it to a variable to have the result. `num = num.replaceFirst("\\+(\\d{2})", "0")`

Comment: actually +92 is not accepting in the  number.replace already tried

Comment: already tested my code and it works. i dont know what is in your code. you can post your code here

Comment: @NoumanShah you need to parse that int into string then try...that code will work for you

Answer (score 1):

you can use substr() and concat with '0' like,

```
String str= "+919025858316";
String newstr ="";

if(str.substring(0,3).equals("+91"))
 {
     newstr = "0" + str.substring(3);
 }
else
 {
    newstr = str;
 }
 System.out.println(newstr);
```

> output is 09025858316

Comment: Assume `String num = "0231235410";` then ur code results wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Check like this :**

```
String num = "+921231231231"; // OR String num = "01231231231";

    if(num.startsWith("+92")) {
        String a = "0" + num.substring(3);
        System.out.println("" + a);
    }else{
        System.out.println("" + num);
    }
```

**Update:**

```
 private String modifyNumber(String num) {
        if(num.startsWith("+92")) {
            num = "0" + num.substring(3);
        }
        return num;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just get the last 10 digit of the string and then you can add the zero.
might be that help you

```
String number= str.substring(Math.max(str.length() - 10, 0));
number ="0"+number;
```

from here you can get the correct phone number without any code.

might be this help you.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is some standardization on mobile numbers in every country. The mobile number is 10 digit. Only here, the last 10 digits are mobile numbers and rest of the digits are country code so take the last 10 digit and add 0 to the first. Then, your problem will be resolved.

**i.e,**

```
String number = "+929918001800";
String newNumber = "0"+number.subString(number.length()-10,number.length());
```

I hope this one will help you :)